Can't save image in Ubuntu for Librosa
Below code is fine to operate in jupyter notebook in Windows.
However, images can't be saved in Jetson Orin Nano in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
I put audio files in "Record" folder.
I checked there are values for "data_5s_y" and "d_data_5s_y".
But plt.savefig doesn't save anything.
Therefore, last line had an error because there aren't any files in "'./Spectrogram/5s/".
As a result, I highly doubt that there is a problem of saving image.
import librosa
import glob
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

hop_length = 1024
num = 0
num_10s = 1

while True:

wav_file = glob.glob('./Record/*.wav')

data_5s_y, data_5s_sr = librosa.load(wav_file[num]) 
 
d_data_5s_y = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(librosa.stft(data_5s_y, hop_length=hop_length)), ref=np.max)

librosa.display.specshow(d_data_5s_y, y_axis='log', x_axis='time', 
                         sr=data_5s_sr, hop_length=hop_length)
plt.axis('off')

filename = wav_file[num].split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]

plt.savefig('./Spectrogram/5s/%s.png' % filename, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)

png_file = glob.glob('./Spectrogram/5s/*.png')

im = Image.open(png_file[0])


Please could you post the full traceback of the error?

I suspect this line filename = wav_file[num].split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0].  Why do you split on '\\'?

Thanks for your help. It was solved. I changed from '\' to'/'. I am too silly :)
